# Graph sorting to reduce "edge-distance"

Tags: compiler-construction

I want my hobby compiler to be able to elide jump instructions between basic blocks.
Therefore I want to sort or rather reorder the control flow graph in such a way, that as many edges as possible appear next to each other in a linear list of the nodes.

E.g. when block `A` is a predessecor of `B`, then `A` shall appear before `B` in a linear list of all blocks for as many predecessor-successor pairs as possible. Then I can safely remove the terminating jump instruction of `A` without changing semantics.

Is there a graph algorithm that archieves this and is this a reasonable approach?

If possible it would also be great to prioritize certain edges e.g. edges in loops.

Comment: To whoever voted to close would you mind to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if anyone is interested, it's actually pretty trivial. A simple depth first search suffices, prioritzed edges can be visited first.